# strcpy in a specific memory address returns value plus garbage

Tags: c

I'm required to save data, which happens to be a char array of 4096 characters tops, in a specified memory address.

So here i get the memory address from a uint32_t into the void* ptrAddress

```
uint32_t number = 1268;
void* ptrAddress = &number;
```

and here i try to copy the array of As, which works! but not really, because i get some garbage in the middle

```
char tryArray[4096];

for(int i = 0; i < 4095; i++ ){

    tryArray[i] = 'A';
}
//EDIT: added the null terminator (forgot to do that)
tryArray[4095] = '\0';

char* copy = strcpy(ptrAddress, (char*)tryArray);

printf("lets see: %s\n", copy);
```

output (imagine 4096 As and 'garbage' as some garbage character):

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'garbage''garbage''garbage'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

And after that i get a seg fault

What am i doing wrong? If there's anything more you need to know from the code or my intentions with it, please tell me!

Comment: End of string terminator missing?

Comment: tryArray[i] = '\0';  after the loop

Comment: Are the locations `&1268` and 4k bytes after that valid memory locations?

Comment: Yes! added null terminator cause i forgot, thanks for that! still get the garbage tho :/

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Thats another thing! i am required to use location &1268, but i cannot be sure memory after that is free. But at the same time, cant use malloc since i'd lose location &1268

Answer (score 4):

You have a couple of problems.

First, this code:

```
uint32_t number = 1268;
void* ptrAddress = &number;
```

Doesn't make a pointer to memory address `1268`, like you seem to indicate you want it to. It makes a pointer to the integer where that `1268` is stored. You then overrun that storage by a lot, causing undefined behaviour, so after that it's game over.

If you want a pointer to a specific memory address:

```
void *ptrAddress = (void *)0x1268;
```

Make sure that address is legit in your environment/address space, though!

Second, `strcpy` works on null-terminated strings. You should probably use `memcpy` if you plan to work with a 4096 byte (non-null terminated) buffer. Note that means you can't print using printf (at least the way you're trying).

```
printf("%-4096s");
```

Should do it though.

Comment: Yeah! I've tried with memcpy() too, but i ran into the same problem. The thing is that I need it to be stored in the memory address &1268, for some reason, but im guessing that may be close to impossible :( Thanks for the reply!

Comment: On embedded micro systems it's not uncommon to have known-numeric memory addresses, where this might make sense, but if this is a regular old C program, it's completely misguided. What suggested to you that 1268 was somehow interesting?